Write $\log(1+(x-y)^2)$ in finite sum of $p_i(x)q_i(y)$
Main question
Is it possible to write $\log(1+(x-y)^2)$ in finite sum of $p_i(x)q_i(y)$, where $p_i,q_i:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are arbitrary functions?
Background
One of my friends have encountered a problem. In virtually any textbook available, it is assumed that the collection of Cauchy distributions,
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{P}=\left\{f(x\mid\theta)=\frac{1}{\pi(1+(x-\theta)^2)}:\theta\in\mathbb{R}\right\}
\end{equation*}
is not a $k$-parameter exponential family for any $k$.
Similar questions on MSE
I have read Why Cauchy Distribution isn't Exponental Family? and How to prove Cauchy Distribution doesn't belong to Exponential Family?, but the answers are not satisfying. What I want is a completely rigorous proof of the statement.
Case when $k=1$
I have solved the case for $k=1$. If it was a $1$-parameter exponential family, we shall have $$1+(x-y)^2=h(x)l(y)e^{p(x)q(y)}\text{ }\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}.$$
Replacing $h$ by $\vert h\vert$ and $l$ by $\vert l\vert$ when necessary and taking logarithm, $$\log(1+(x-y)^2)=f(x)+g(y)+p(x)q(y)\text{ }\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}.$$
Now, suppose $x_1\neq x_2$.
$$\log(1+(x_1-y)^2)-\log(1+(x_2-y)^2)=f(x_1)-f(x_2)+(p(x_1)-p(x_2))q(y)\text{ }\forall y\in\mathbb{R}.$$
Suppose $p$ is not injective, then $\log(1+(x_1-y)^2)-\log(1+(x_2-y)^2)$ would be a constant, which is not true. Similarly, $q$ is injective. But this means that
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\log(1+(x_1-y)^2)-\log(1+(x_2-y)^2)-(f(x_1)-f(x_2))}{p(x_1)-p(x_2)}
\end{equation*}
is an injective function of $y$ for any $x_1\neq x_2$. This is not true, and we arrive at a contradiction.
General case
The general case is equivalent to have functions $p_i,q_i:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ for $i=1,\dots,k,$ so that
\begin{equation*}
1+(x-y)^2=h(x)l(y)\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^kp_i(x)q_i(y)\right)\text{ }\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}.
\end{equation*}
By taking $p_{k+1}(x)=h(x),q_{k+1}(y)=1$ and $p_{k+2}(x)=1,q_{k+2}(y)=l(y)$, we may ignore the things outside $\exp$ and write
$$\log(1+(x-y)^2)=\sum_{i=1}^{k+2}p_i(x)q_i(y).$$
And for this I barely have an idea of how to do.
Any help would be appreciated!

to be honest I didn't read the full question, but in this question of mine I made some approximations for splitting the logarithm of a sum that maybe could help you.

Obviously not: $f(i,j)$ is an infinite rank matrix.

@fedja Would you mind providing more details?

@TonyMa One property of functions $f$ in the form of finite sums of $p(x)q(y)$ is that: for $n$ large enough and any $n$ reals $x_1,\cdots,x_n$, the determinant of $(f(x_i,x_j))$ is zero. Now it suffices to prove that for some $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ this determinant is nonzero.

The answer is No.
Lemma. Let $f(x,y)=\mathbb{log}(1+(x-y)^2)$. For all $n\ge1$, there exists distinct real numbers $x_i,y_i(1\le i  \le n)$ that $\mathbb{det}(A)\ne 0$ for $A=(a_{ij})=(f(x_i,y_j))$.
Proof by induction. $n=1$ case is trivial. Now assume $n-1$ case proved, that is the $n-1\times n-1$ matrix $A_0=(f(x_i,y_j)),i,j\le n-1$ being nonsingular. Choose an arbitrary $y_n$. Consider $x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1},y_1,\cdots,y_n$ as fixed, $x_n$ as a variable and denote the $n\times n$ matrix $A(x_n)=(f(x_i,y_j))$. By the laplace expansion on the last row of $A(x_n)$, we get
$$\mathbb{det}(A(x_n))=\sum_{i=1}^n {(-1)^i A_i f(x_i,y_{n+1-i})}$$
where $A_i$ is the determinant of $n-1\times n-1$ submatrix of $A(x_n)$ in the first $n-1$ rows. (Obviously there are $n$ submatrices). By induction we have $A_1=\mathbb{det}(A_0)$ nonzero. Hence $\mathbb{exp}(\mathbb{det}(A(x_n)))$ is of the form $\prod{(1+(x_n-y_i)^2)^{\pm A_i}}$. Since all $y_i$ are distinct and $A_1 \ne 0$, there should exist $x_n$ that make $\mathbb{exp}(\mathbb{det}(A(x_n)))\ne 1$ and all $x_i,y_i$ distinct (the detailed proof should be very complicated). Hence $\mathbb{det}(A(x_n))\ne 0$, as claimed.
Now we solve the original problem. If we have $f(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^n {p_i(x)q_i(y)}$, then for any $2n+2$ real numbers $x_1,\cdots,x_{n+1},y_1,\cdots,y_{n+1}$, consider the matrix $A=(f(x_i,y_j))$. It has determinant
$$\mathbb{det}A=\sum_{1\le k_i \le n,i=1,\dots,n+1} {\mathbb{det}((p_{k_i}(x_i)q_{k_i}(y_j)))}$$
By pigeonhole principle, each of the matrices on the RHS has two rows (corresponding to $i_1$ and $i_2$) that $k_{i_1}=k_{i_2}$, hence proportional, hence has determinant $0$. So $A$ also has determinant $0$, which contradicts the lemma.
